# What happens if the number of keep-alive connections reaches MaxIdleConns in Golang http transport

Tags: http, go, tcp, transport

I have some questions when using http.Transport to setup http client

Assume we have `MaxIdleConns=10`, `MaxIdleConnsPerHost=2`, five different hosts each of which has two keep-live connections and that means the number of connections reach `MaxIdleConns`.

1. What will client do when a new connection whose target host maybe one of the five hosts is needed?
2. What will client do when a new different host connection is needed?

By the way, if I have an server using `http.ListenAndServe`, how to configure it, like when to close keep-live connections? I would be grateful if there were any example codes.

Comment: The client will reuse idle keepalive connections if possible. If none of them can be reused and it's at its limit, it will close one. Are you seeing some other behavior or running into  some kind of issue?

Comment: I had many keep-live connections, the new request always failed beacause of "can't assign requested address". which is solved by share a http client. But i has some questions about its processing logic, and I didn't find that in source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the default Go HTTP client, it will throw an error `"too many open files error"` when you reach the maximum connection limit during high frequency API calls. This happens because, the default HTTP client won't close the connections once created. In order to solve this issue, you have to create a custom HTTP client and set a timeout interval.

```
var netTransport = &http.Transport{
  Dial: (&net.Dialer{
    Timeout: 5 * time.Second,
  }).Dial,
  TLSHandshakeTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
}
var netClient = &http.Client{
  Timeout: time.Second * 10,
  Transport: netTransport,
}
response, _ := netClient.Get(url)
```

Refer this link for more details, refer this link https://medium.com/@nate510/don-t-use-go-s-default-http-client-4804cb19f779

Comment: That is very helpful, by the way, how to set the configuration for golang http server

Comment: server := &http.Server{
  Addr:         //Listen port,
  Handler:      //Handler config,
  ErrorLog:     //Logger config,
  ReadTimeout:  5 * time.Second,
  WriteTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
  IdleTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
 }

 server.ListenAndServe()